# Curl for ":" in web url

Tags: bash, curl

I am writing a program in bash and want to use curl to display the contents of a website.  The website url is http://examplewebsite.com/example.php?pass=hello hello:world.  Using:

`curl http://examplewebsite.com/example.php?pass=hello hello:world`

However this returns:
`Couldn't resolve host 'hello:world'`

Comment: http://php.net/urlencode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error was caused by the space between “hello” and “world” that caused bash to split the link into two different tokens, which curl interpreted as two different links.

You should at least quote the URL parameters, as Explosion Pills did.

However, it is not a good style to pass arguments directly like that, because you might end up with some characters that need escaping (space is one of those, but it seems to be handled automatically by curl).

To do this, you can use the `--data-urlencode`:

```
curl "http://examplewebsite.com/example.php" --data-urlencode "pass=hello hello:world" --get
```

(`--data-urlencode` switches the method to POST instead of GET, so you can use `--get` to switch back to GET)

Comment: I just ended by using `curl --data` with post

Comment: "It is not a good style to pass arguments directly like that." Actually it's not only bad style; it's just wrong. RFC 3986 doesn't allow spaces in URIs. Depending on the implementation it might work, but there's definitely no guarantee (I believe).

Answer (score 2):

Just wrap the URL in a string:

```
curl "http://examplewebsite.com/example.php?pass=hello hello:world"
```

Your mileage may vary as to whether this works properly or not, so you should also URL encode the value:

```
curl "http://examplewebsite.com/example.php?pass=hello%22hello%3Aworld"
```